# Performing Arithmetic operations on nested dataframe containing a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called dailyHistogram defined as follows:

> ```
> dailyHistogram = pd.DataFrame({'NumVisits':[[0 for x in range(1440)]
>                                         for y in range (180)],
>                                 'DoW': [0]*ReportingDateRange.size
>                           }
>                          ,columns=['NumVisits','DoF'],
>                           index=ReportingDateRange)
> ```

Where NumVisits is a two-dimensional array (1440 by 180) and holds a histogram of some activity in 180 days. DoW is simply a column which holds the day of the week. 
The index in this dataframe is the dates on which the activities occurred.

My problem is in performing any operations on dailyHistogram["NumVisits"].

Here's what dailyHistogram["NumVisits"] looks like:

```
> dailyHistogram["NumVisits"] 

> Out[193]:  
> 2016-01-01    [5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> 
> 2016-01-02    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> 
> 2016-01-03    [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> 
> 2016-01-04    [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> 
> 2016-06-26    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> 
> 2016-06-27    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
> 
> 2016-06-28    [7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
> 
> 2016-06-29    [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> 
> 2016-06-30    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
> 
> Freq: D, Name: NumVisits, dtype: object
```

I'd like to sum up all vectors in "NumVisits" for a particular day of the week, but no arithmetic operations seem to be possible on dailyHistogram["NumVisits"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `NumVisits` is a list, and to perform arithmetic on the contents of a list, you need to explicitly apply your functions. For example:

```
df['NumVisits'].apply(sum)
```

---

For element by element sum in each row:

```
import numpy as np
df['NumVisits'].apply(np.cumsum)
```

---

For sum across all rows, for each element in row:

```
np.array(dailyHistogram['NumVisits'].tolist()).sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I was looking for. 
Is there any way, to get a list that contains the element by element sum of all NumVisits?

Comment: Thank you so much for suggesting CUMSUM.
CUMSUM does an element by element summation for each row. What if I want all first elements in each row summed up together? I'm talking about a vertical element by element summation along the columns as opposed to a horizontal one.

Comment: For that, you have to convert it to a DataFrame, or do something else... See this [blog post](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_expand_cells_containing_lists.html)