# Summing list element in nested dataframe vertically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called dailyHistogram defined as follows:

```
dailyHistogram = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'NumVisits':[[0 for x in range(1440)] for y in range (180)],
        'DoW': [0]*ReportingDateRange.size
    },
    columns=['NumVisits','DoF'],
    index=ReportingDateRange
)
```

Where NumVisits is a two-dimensional array (1440 by 180) and holds a histogram of some activity in 180 days. DoW is simply a column which holds the day of the week. The index in this dataframe is the dates on which the activities occurred.

My problem is in performing any operations on dailyHistogram["NumVisits"].

Here's what dailyHistogram["NumVisits"] looks like:

> dailyHistogram["NumVisits"]
>
> Out[193]:
> 2016-01-01    [5, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> 2016-01-02    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> 2016-01-03    [6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> 2016-01-04    [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> 2016-06-26    [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> 2016-06-27    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
>
> 2016-06-28    [7, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...
>
> 2016-06-29    [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> 2016-06-30    [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
>
> Freq: D, Name: NumVisits, dtype: object

I'd like to sum up each element of dailyHistogram["NumVisits"] vertically to arrive at one list with 1440 members.

Comment: I answered this question in you previous question. This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618387/performing-arithmetic-operations-on-nested-dataframe-containing-a-list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [84]: dailyHistogram
Out[84]:
                        NumVisits  DoF
0  [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]  NaN
1  [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]  NaN
2  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]  NaN
3  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]  NaN
4  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]  NaN

In [85]: dailyHistogram.NumVisits.apply(pd.Series).sum().tolist()
Out[85]: [4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2, 5, 2]
```

Setup:

```
dailyHistogram = pd.DataFrame({'NumVisits':[[np.random.choice([0,1]) for x in range(10)]
                                               for y in range (5)],
                                'DoW': [0]*5}
                              ,columns=['NumVisits','DoF'])
```